# DIV after position:absolute

Tags: css, css-position

i put `div` with `class="inner-box2"` after `div` with `class="inner-box"`.

HTML:

```
 <div class="box">

   <div class="inner-box"></div>

   <div class="inner-box2"></div>

 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .box {
     position: relative;
     width: 400px;
     height: 400px;
     border: solid 10px red;
  }

  .inner-box {
    border: solid 10px blue;
    position: absolute;
    height:150px;
    width:380px;

  }
   .inner-box2 {
    border: solid 10px green;
  }
```

Now, I need to show `div(inner-box2)` after `div(inner-box)` but in my Code `div(inner-box2)` show in under `div(inner-box)`. how to fix this? See [Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BBKING/4bqzz/)

Comment: Not possible. Absolutely positioned elements are outside the document layout flow. Why do you need `.inner-box` to be absolutely positioned anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are putting an element below the absolute position, you can add a margin to bump down your next element the distance required to "skip" the absolute item's space and presence.  That way in the code, the item is still below your absolute item, but still visually appears below it.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely-positioned items need to have `top`|`bottom` + `left`|`right` defined.

Comment: I believe this is just to normalize some IE quirks. Nevertheless, it doesn't actually solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use absolutely positioned elements in this example, this would be how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/4bqzz/106/

```
.box
{
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: solid 10px red;
}
.inner-box
{
    border: solid 10px blue;
    position: absolute; 
    height: 150px;
    width: 380px;
}
.inner-box2
{
    border: solid 10px green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    height: 210px;
    width: 380px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are shooting for http://jsfiddle.net/4bqzz/22/? I've modded your css a bit, and then floated the boxes left.  You can play around with the sizes, borders, etc...  But I assume they were so thick just to demonstrate where they were. Like so:

```
     .inner-box {
      border: solid 5px blue;
      float:left;
      height:150px;
      width:360px;
  }
  .inner-box2 {
      border: solid 5px green;
      float:left;
      height:150px;
      width:20px;
  }
```